# read excel files in jupyter however some rows missing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm reading an excel file in jupyter, however some rows missing, can someone help?
Cheers. 
here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("/Users/sudd2010126.com/Desktop/2019_semester_1/FIT_5147/Project_source/causes_of_death_australia.xlsx")
data
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkUu3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Rows are not missing, it's just not printed on display because it has too many rows. If you want to change this option and display all the rows, you can do so by changing [Pandas Options and Settings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```